# How to over come type mismatch in scala

Tags: scala

```
def getDesiredValue(measure: String, value: String): Any = {

    val desiredMeasure = List("temperature","speed","length")
    if(desiredMeasure.contains(measure)){
        measure match
        {
            case temperature => value
            case speed => value
            case length => value
        }
        value.toString
    }

}

val Value = getDesiredValue("temperature", "°C")
```

Compile error:

```
found : Unit
required: String

if(desiredMeasure.contains(measure)){
^
```

Though the "Value" is passed to the function, it should only return for elements in the List("temperature","speed","length"), bypass for rest of the inputs.

Comment: You need to return something if your `if`-test doesn't match.

Comment: What do you want `getDesiredValue` to return?

Comment: "value" should be returned by the getDesiredValue

Comment: `value` is passed in to the function so if the function just returns `value` then there doesn't seem to be any point in calling the function.  If the comments and answers don't help then you may need to give some more information about what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: only for the elemnts in the List("temperature","speed","length") it should return the "value"

Answer (score 4):

This is a better way to structure this code and should fix the error you are seeing:

```
def getDesiredValue(measure: String, value: String) =
  measure match {
    case "temperature" => value
    case "speed" => value
    case "length" => value
    case _ => errorValue
  }
```